# Visual Studio 2003 and IIS

Tags: c#

is there anyway I can run my web application from Visual Studio 2003 without calling any IIS web server or localhost?

Appreciate anyone who can answer the above.

Comment: Do you mean Debug? Without calling IIS? No there is none. Even the new ASP.NET 5 that can run in different platform server needs to debug from IIS server. It is only the Deployment part that will be different.

Comment: Why do you think a one line question would be acceptable here?  We have very high quality standards.

Comment: Oh, it is 2003. My mistake. I thought it is 2013. Instead I think Webruster answers can help you out. Although the Article writer is not sure for himself. So you can say it is a hacky way, but WWFY(What ever Works FOR YOU) is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you want to `Debug` without IIS in Visual Studio 2003 ..If my assumption is right please refer [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/scottkuhl/archive/2005/09/13/DebugASPNETWithoutIISinVisualStudioNET2003.aspx) article